# Please help me about complex sentence

Tags: grammar

I have this sentence: "A typical characteristic of EDM is that the cavity cut by the tool electrode is larger than the tool itself." I want to determine whether it is a simple or complex sentence. A complex sentence must contain at least two clauses: one independent clause and one or more dependent clauses. The mentioned sentence includes a nominal clause "that the cavity cut by the tool electrode is larger than the tool itself", which acts as a dependent clause. The question then is whether the remaining "A typical characteristic of EDM is" can be considered an independent clause. Is it a complete thought to be classified as an independent clause?

Comment: Questions about English grammar fit better on https://english.stackexchange.com.